# .htaccess redirect - infinite loop without [R] flag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to use beautiful URLs on my site. I want to redirect

example.com/page-title/ to example.com/?q=page-title

The following .htaccess code works fine, but it does an HTTP redirect because of the [R] flag:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)/*$ https://www.example.com/?q=$1 [L,R]
```

Obviously I want to do an internal redirect, but when I remove the [R] flag it goes into an redirect loop.

1. Why with the [R] flag it does not loop, and without it it does?
2. How do I avoid the loop without the [R] flag?

Comment: Change your rule to this: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?q=$1 [L,QSA]` and completely clear your cache.

Comment: Yeah I figured the problem is including the whole URL. Without it Apache cannot detect and disable the loop. Feel free to post an answer if you and so that I select it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be that you have `http://` in your target. Even without `R` flag if Apache sees a full URL that has `http://` or `https://` in target then it performs a full redirect with `R=302`.

You can just use rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```